# Why is this value printed although being NaN?

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

The following code assumes that we are on an x86-compatible system and that `long double` maps to x87 FPU's 80-bit format.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<uint8_t,10> data1{0x52,0x23,0x6f,0x24,0x8f,0xac,0xd1,0x43,0x30,0x02};
    std::array<uint8_t,10> data2{0x52,0x23,0x6f,0x24,0x8f,0xac,0xd1,0xc3,0x30,0x02};
    std::array<uint8_t,10> data3{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x30,0x02};
    long double value1, value2, value3;
    static_assert(sizeof value1 >= 10,"Expected float80");
    std::memcpy(&value1, data1.data(),sizeof value1);
    std::memcpy(&value2, data2.data(),sizeof value2);
    std::memcpy(&value3, data3.data(),sizeof value3);
    std::cout << "isnan(value1): " << std::boolalpha << std::isnan(value1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "isnan(value2): " << std::boolalpha << std::isnan(value2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "isnan(value3): " << std::boolalpha << std::isnan(value3) << "\n";
    std::cout << "value1: " << std::setprecision(20) << value1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "value2: " << std::setprecision(20) << value2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "value3: " << std::setprecision(20) << value3 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

> isnan(value1): true
>
> isnan(value2): false
>
> isnan(value3): false
>
> value1: 3.3614005946481929011e-4764
>
> value2: 9.7056260598879139386e-4764
>
> value3: 6.3442254652397210376e-4764

Here `value1` is classified as "unsupported" by 387 and higher, because it has nonzero and not all-ones exponent — it's in fact an "unnormal". And `isnan` works as expected with it: the value is indeed nothing of a number (although not exactly a NaN). The second value, `value2`, has that integer bit set, and also works as expected: it's not a NaN. The third one is the value of the missing integer bit.

But somehow both numbers `value1` and `value2` appear printed, and the values differ exactly by the missing integer bit! Why is that? All other methods I tried, like `printf` and `to_string` give just `0.00000`.

Even stranger, if I do any arithmetic with `value1`, in subsequent prints I do get `nan`. Taking this into account, how does `operator<<(long double)` even manage to actually print anything but `nan`? Does it explicitly set the integer bit, or maybe it parses the number instead of doing any FPU arithmetic on it? (assuming g++4.8 on Linux 32 bit).

Comment: This is probably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518951/engineered-bool-compares-equal-to-both-true-and-false-why. The implementation is entitled to assume that what you give it contains a valid `long double` representation (or `bool` in the linked question). If you pass it an invalid representation, all bets are off.

Comment: UB Is U. Why should you expect any particular behavior?

Comment: “it's in fact an "unnormal". And isnan works as expected with it: the value is indeed nothing of a number” This is not what “NaN” means. NaN is a floating-point value that will propagate through computations in a specified way. An unnormal value is a historical remnant and it has been unsupported to pass one to a floating-point instruction since the 387. For practical purposes, an unnormal value should be considered a “trap representation” that invokes undefined behavior upon use, not a NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All other methods I tried, like printf and to_string give just
>   0.00000.

What `operator<<(long double)` actually does is using the `num_put<>` class from `locale` library to perform the numeric formatting, which in turn uses one of the `printf`-family functions (see sections 27.7.3.6 and 22.4.2.2 of the C++ standard).

Depending on the settings, printf conversion specifier used for `long double` by `locale` might be any of: `%Lf`, `%Le`, `%LE`, `%La`, `%LA`, `%Lg` or `%LG`.

In your (and my) case it seems to be `%Lg`:

```
printf("value1: %.20Lf\n", value1);
printf("value1: %.20Le\n", value1);
printf("value1: %.20La\n", value1);
printf("value1: %.20Lg\n", value1);
std::cout << "value1: " << std::setprecision(20) << value1 << "\n";
```

> value1: 0.00000000000000000000
>
> value1: 3.36140059464819290106e-4764
>
> value1: 0x4.3d1ac8f246f235200000p-15826
>
> value1: 3.3614005946481929011e-4764
>
> value1: 3.3614005946481929011e-4764

---

> Taking this into account, how does operator<<(long double) even manage
>   to actually print anything but nan? Does it explicitly set the integer
>   bit, or maybe it parses the number instead of doing any FPU arithmetic
>   on it?

It prints the unnormalized value.

Conversion from binary to decimal floating point representation used by `printf()` may be performed without any FPU arithmetics. You can find the glibc implementation in the `stdio-common/printf_fp.c` source file.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this:

```cpp
long double value = std::numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN();
std::cout << "isnan(value): " << std::boolalpha << std::isnan(value) << "\n";
std::cout << "value: " << std::setprecision(20) << value << "\n";
```

So my *assumption* is that as stated here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan value is being cast to double and not long double when evaluated by `std::isnan` and strictly:

```cpp
std::numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN() != std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()
```

Comment: NaN is by definition unequal to itself as well as to anything else, regardless of type.